# What are some good books on foundations of Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, information

I am not looking for some introductory texts, graduate text, etc. I am looking for something that addresses to foundational problems in thermodynamics and statistical mechanics.

Comment: What would you consider to be a "foundational problem" in thermodynamics? In statistical mechanics the great white whale is the ergodic hypothesis, which is not as universal as we would like. Is that what you are thinking about? Otherwise both thermodynamics and statistical mechanics are essentially a few definitions and their mathematical consequences... most of which should be covered by the usual textbooks.

Comment: I want a book that explains the whys. I know this request is vague but that's what I want. Jaynes papers explained for me things related to entropy. I want something of that sort.

Comment: The "whys" in physics are experiments. Do you want a textbook that contains the crucial historical experiments in thermodynamics?

Comment: @CuriousOne I found the book, 'Information Dynamics and Open Systems' by R S Ingarden, Kossakowski, M Ohya quite good.